# pagination ajax in codeigniter with load data otomatis from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

i try to load data from database otomatis, input from phpmyadmin with query and otomatis data can show in view AJAX, then i try to join with pagination AJAX. this my code to show otomatis :
model :

```
function get_all_transaksi_proses() {
        $limit=10; $offset = 0;   
        $rs = $this->db->query("SELECT a.id_transaksi, a.nama, a.tgl_transaksi, 
        (SELECT COUNT( id_transaksi ) AS jum FROM tbl_detail_trs_menu WHERE id_transaksi = a.id_transaksi) 
        AS jumlah, a.status_transaksi, a.total, b.status_pelanggan, c.nama_karyawan FROM tbl_transaksi a LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_pelanggan b ON a.id_pelanggan = b.id_pelanggan LEFT JOIN tbl_karyawan c ON a.id_karyawan = 
        c.id_karyawan WHERE a.status_transaksi =  'PROSES' LIMIT ".$offset.",".$limit."");  
        return $rs;
    }
```

control :

```
public function ambilDataTransaksi() {
                      $data=$data=$this->transaksi->get_all_transaksi_proses();
                      echo json_encode(array("result" => $data->result_array()));
        }
```

view :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {        
        selesai();
});

function selesai() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        update();
        selesai();
    }, 200);
}

function update() {

    $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url();?>transaksiDigorCont/ambilDataTransaksi", function(data) {

        $(".dataku").empty();
        $no=1;
        $.each(data.result, function() { 

        $(".dataku").append(

                "<tr><td>"+$no+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['id_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['nama']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['tgl_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['jumlah']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['status_transaksi']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['total']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['status_pelanggan']+"</td>\n\
                <td>"+this['nama_karyawan']+"</td><td>"+this['nama_karyawan']+"</td></tr>");
        $no++;});
    });
}

</script>
```

so why i implement pagination in this code... thx u

Comment: you want to add pagination here right?

Comment: yes... how? @Ramesh Mhetre

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add pagination library, logic create offset & limit, and load view of listing like wise... (Place normal pagination code here)

Write this jquery code on your view to load different pages :

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#pagination-div-id a").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: $(this).attr("href"),
   data:"q=<?php echo $searchString; ?>",
   success: function(res){
      $("#containerid").html(res);
   }
   });
   return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

like wise... You need to do some dig & dag over here.. But this way is working for me.

Here is one link for reference & detailed example : http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/122597/